What Exactly was The Baptist Saying?
John the Baptist is a central figure in Christianity.  Sent by God as shown by the prophets, he prepared the way of the Lord, the way of Jesus Christ (Malachi 3:1, Mt 3:3, 11:10).
John was of the priestly Levitical tribe in the order of Abijah, being born of Zechariah and Elizabeth, both of whom were of Levi (1 Ch 24:10, Luke 1:5).
When John was preaching and baptizing, it is important to note for this question, he did so apart and away from the temple in Jerusalem.  He preached in the wilderness.  He baptized in the Jordan.  (See Mt. 3:1, Mar 1:4.)  The point is he did this without reference to the Levitical system of confession of sin and sacrifice.  (See Lev 4, 23, etc.)
With these things in mind, from a Trinitarian position, what exactly was John the Baptist preaching apart from the temple system when he said repent?
Repent means change your mind.  Metanoeo, Strong's G3340, to think differently, to reconsider.
How would this change prepare the way of the Lord?  How would it make straight His paths?

Can you expand on why Trinitarianism is relevant to this question.

@RayButterworth Why does someone need to justify requesting answers from a particular viewpoint ? Surely this is the prerogative of the OP ? It does not need to be 'relevant to this question'. Question up-voted +1.

@NigelJ The outcome of answers desired by the questionnaire depends on the information given. "From a trinitarian position" might completely change the dynamics of someone's answer. Instead of focusing on what John was doing separate from the Law and why, now possibly has to be about the the coming together of trinitarian the aspects.

@Biff Exactly. That is why it is the prerogative of the OP.

@NigelJ, your answer for instance seems to ignore this restriction and has nothing obvious to do with Trinitarianism. Does that mean that it isn't a good answer to the question?  I don't think so, so what was the point of requiring it in the question?  That isn't a rhetorical question; the OP must have had a reason for it, but I really don't understand why the question mentions "Trinitarian position".

@NigelJ - Peoples request for clarification shouldn't be seen as someone trying to be difficult. I was thinking the same thing as Ray. I had begun to formulate the direction of which to reply, but the trinitarian viewpoint inclusion made me think that maybe the OP was wanting a trinitarian outcome, which I then needed clarifiaction myself as to if this was a question that I wanted to provide an answer for.

@RayButterworth I understand what you are saying and I agree in that my answer did not need to include anything that was, distinctively, Trinitarian. But I do think it is proper to respect the right of the OP to ask for responses from a particular viewpoint. I think it is quite fundamental to the function of the site to do so. Questions may be closed for not specifying such a scoping. Perhaps this needs a question on Meta for clarification.

@NigelJ, I'm not concerned with whether the question asks for a Trinitarian perspective. The problem is that I can't think of how that perspective would affect the answer, but the inclusion of the condition implies that the OP does think it is significant. So any answer that doesn't make some Trinitarian connection must be missing what the OP was looking for. So yes, the OP has the right to ask for a specific perspective, but there is a corresponding obligation to indicate why they think that perspective could affect the answer.

From a Trinitarian perspective was simply my attempt at restricting answers to Catholics, Orthodox, Baptist, Lutheran, etc.  And not from groups that do not agree with what might be termed "traditional Christianity".  Although, from the answers given, the perspective is very applicable.  Sorry for any confusion though.

@NigelJ  Probably well enough covered by others, but, my brain submitted a request for Defcon 3.5 when it met the trinitarian comment. ie I quite unconsciously felt that something subtle or maybe not so subtle had happened to the question.  Ray's original request seemes extremely appropriate. It's not a matter of approval or disapproval or needing to support or a oppose a viewpoint - it just that knowing what the OP has in mind makes it vastly more likely that a good answer can be provided.

A trinitarian person will view the one whom John the Baptist pointed to as God incarnate. This will give them an advantage in understanding what John was on about, which Judaic people will not have. A relevant point, given that the question notes how John called for a repentance and baptism apart from the Judaic sacrificial / temple system.
It is worth bearing in mind that although there seemed to have been a general expectation of the foretold Messiah arriving around that time, the challenge of John to those who only knew the Judaic system was for baptism of Jewish people. Up till then, only proselytes were required to be baptised. But John only addressed his preaching to Jewish people - the House of Israel. He did not call Gentiles to confess their sins and to be baptised. He challenged those already in the Mosaic Law Covenant to do something more.
He was saying that Jewish people needed to confess their sins and be baptised, in preparation for the arrival of the promised Messiah. He said, "For the law was given by Moses, but grace and truth came by Jesus Christ" (John 1:17). And he also said, categorically, that he was not that expected Saviour. Which makes his challenge to confess and be baptised all the more remarkable, for the people might have expected Messiah to say that - not one who was 'only' preparing the way for him.
What else did John say? He castigated hypocrites who came to him (Luke 3:3-9), then told the people to give their spare coat to one having none; same with food; for tax collectors to be honest; same for soldiers, plus not to be violent and to be content with their wages (vss. 10-14). And he pointed to the coming One as being before him, mighty, and baptizing with the Holy Spirit and with fire (vs. 16). Then he testified to the Holy Spirit descending on Christ at his baptism, and hearing the voice from heaven saying, "This is my beloved Son, in whom I am well pleased" (vs. 22).
The exact meaning of John's call to repentance and baptism? To prepare the Jewish people who responded, so that they could then receive the Messiah.  After Messiah then appeared, coming to John for baptism, John publicly declared him to be "The Lamb of God that takes away the sin of the world" (John 1:29). John said he would then decrease, while Christ would increase. John said he was not "that true Light but was sent to bear witness of that Light" (vss. 8-13). Those who believed in the name of Jesus, who received him, would become sons of God, born of God (vs. 12-13).
Clearly, John's exact mission was to prepare Jewish people to receive Jesus Christ, by identifying Christ, and calling those who were to follow Christ to repent and be baptised. Then, and only then, would those prepared people recognise and respond to Christ, following him (and not John).
This means that John was not preaching a system (the Temple system); he was preaching the person of the Son of God. This one had to be greater than the Temple (as Jesus said later); greater than the daily and annual sacrifices in the Temple. John did not offer people forgiveness of sins; only Jesus could give that, because of his deity. And this is the crunch point, where the trinitarian perspective gives understanding.
Those supporting the Temple system, and its sacrifices, took offense at Jesus forgiving sins, for only God can do that. Those who admire Jesus but say he was 'only' a perfect man, likewise take offense at his deity, trying to say there are ways to receive Christ without belief in his full deity. However, from the trinitarian point of view, what John the Baptist said underscores the deity of Christ.
Finally, it was not people having to change their minds about Christ that John was on about. They had to receive new minds, and a new heart, wherein the seed of the gospel of Christ would then take root and grow productively. This is where Jesus' parable of the 4 types of soil makes sense (Mark 4:13-20). Only properly prepared ground (soil) would produce a people prepared to receive Christ, due to having confessed their sins - thus being made ready for the gospel of grace to then take root. Being prepared is not an intellectual exercise, as John showed. It is about humility and confession before the Messiah, the Christ, recognising him for who he is, and that one's self is a sinner needing forgiveness.

"John did not offer people forgiveness of sins; only Jesus could give that, because of his deity. And this is the crunch point, where the trinitarian perspective gives understanding."  Interesting and insightful.

How would this change prepare the way of the Lord? How would it make straight His paths?

I have answered this question by copying two pages from the book 'The Beginning of the Gospel', Belmont Publications, the author being myself.
The entire book is available free of charge as a PDF download. There is no requirement to register.

The Greek word commonly translated repentance in the AV is metanoia. Meta means change. Noia means mind. But this is not what we casually refer to as a “change of mind”. What is usually meant by that is, actually, a change of opinion or, even
more superficially, a change of decision.
To change one’s opinions is not to repent.
Repentance is to have the mind itself changed, not merely its contents. Repentance is to have a different mind, with a different way of working.
The beginning of the gospel is the changed mind which results from the ministry of a preparative messenger. A changed mind is suited to an honest and good heart.
For this is the covenant that I will make with the house of Israel, saith the Lord,
Hebrews 8:10. Not according to the covenant that I made with their fathers. They continued not in my covenant - that is, the first covenant, the legal covenant made with natural man - and I regarded them not, saith the Lord.
No, this is the covenant that the Lord makes with the house of Israel - that is the true seed, not natural Israel after the flesh - I will put my laws into their mind, dianoia, and write them in their hearts: and I will be to them a God and they shall be to me a people.
When God gives a man a new mind, in which he writes his laws; and a new heart, in which he also writes his laws; then, in such a condition, after such a baptism, is a man ready to receive the messenger of the covenant.
The Beginning of the Gospel, pp 43&45, Belmont Publications, Nigel Johnstone

As to any Trinitarian aspect, the very fact that Mark introduces John the Baptist in relation to the prophecy by Malachi :

Behold, I will send my messenger, and he shall prepare the way before me: and the Lord, whom ye seek, shall suddenly come to his temple, even the messenger of the covenant, [Malachi 3:1 KJV]

... indicates that the one whom John the Baptist precedes is the Messenger of the Covenant and is 'the Lord whom ye seek'. Thus the preparatory messenger, John the Baptist heralds the Lord himself and this aids the Trinitarian reader as to what message it will be that John has to give.

Upon whom thou shalt see the Spirit descending, and remaining on him, the same is he which baptizeth with the Holy Ghost.
And I saw, and bare record that this is the Son of God.
John 1:33,34


"The beginning of the gospel is the changed mind which results from the ministry of a preparative messenger. A changed mind is suited to an honest and good heart."  Can you expand on what that means?  What were they changing their mind about?

@SLM The parable of the Sower is very relevant. Cultivating the heart (not being trampled on by all and sundry) removing the hardness (stony) which will prevent the word penetrating and the removal of other forms of life ~(which will compete and eventually choke the word) .

Repent essentially means to despair in ourselves and our own goodness, works, merit or holiness and to be ready to trust in another’s merits, holiness and righteousness. Deny our own ability to please God through obedience to his laws and be ready for a Lamb of God to do that for us. That is how John the Baptists prepared the way and it is obvious that this is true for anyone who confesses their own sin.  The Pharisees were unwilling to repent but Christ's disciples were. This repentance is changing the mind from unbelief and works, to faith in the promise which alone produces genuine works of live from gratitude. It is an absolute total change of mind for this is not a natural way of thinking being that human nature is born under the broken covenant of works.
The arrival of the long awaited Promise of grace ‘was at hand’ and those who believed in the new covenant joined into this new invisible kingdom by faith. ‘Repent and believe’ is the path to God. This path is in opposition to the old covenant of works under the moral law in obtaining righteousness by one’s own obedience for these are at best filthy rags.
We all need to repent and believe therefore to receive Christ. Anyone who babbles about their works has neither seen or knows God. They need to repent!!

"Repent essentially means to despair in ourselves and our own goodness, works, merit or holiness and to be ready to trust in another’s merits, holiness and righteousness. Deny our own ability to please God through obedience to his laws and be ready for a Lamb of God to do that for us."  Nice contrast.

The provision of a hermetical answer to this question is difficult because it really needs a lot of theology and interpretation to do it any justice.
There is a lot of exegesis to be used since these things are all previously symbolized and prophesied about in the O.T.
The picture is Galilee (heaven), the Dead sea (Sheol) and the connecting Jordan river that washes the sins of people to the Dead sea so that they might ascend into Galilee.
Jerusalem at the time was a place of sin and idolatry. The idolatry is seen with a king that exalts himself (Herod), a temple that is vacant of the presence of God and the priesthood is just going through the motions, and the abomination of a Gentile nation planted as the authority over the land causing people to render everything to Caesar. This may be why the purification of the people had moved into the wilderness as opposed to Jerusalem. John is acting as a priest in the wilderness performing the purification of the people by water.
In connection, the Israelites went into the wilderness and before they were to come into the promised land, they were to cross the Jordan.
Joshua 3:3 - “When you see the ark of the covenant of the Lord your God (Messiah), and the priests, the Levites (John), bearing it, then you shall set out from your place and go after it.
v.5 - Joshua said to the people, “Sanctify yourselves (baptism), for tomorrow the Lord will do wonders among you.”
v.7 - the Lord said to Joshua, “This day I will begin to exalt you in the sight of all Israel, that they may know that, as I was with Moses, so I will be with you. 8 You shall command the priests (John) who bear the ark of the covenant (Messiah), saying, ‘When you have come to the edge of the water of the Jordan, you shall stand in the Jordan.’ ”
v.10 - Joshua said, “By this you shall know that the living God is among you, and that He will without fail drive out from before you the Canaanites and the Hittites and the Hivites and the Perizzites and the Girgashites and the Amorites and the Jebusites (which represent sin in the land)
11 Behold, the ark of the covenant of the Lord of all the earth is crossing over before you into the Jordan. (This is the exact imagery of Mt 3:13, Mk 1:9, Lk 3:21, Jn 1:29)
Joshua 3: - Now therefore, take for yourselves twelve men from the tribes of Israel (disciples), one man from every tribe. 13 And it shall come to pass, as soon as the soles of the feet of the priests who bear the ark of the Lord, the Lord of all the earth, shall rest in the waters of the Jordan, that the waters of the Jordan shall be cut off, the waters that come down from upstream, and they shall stand as a heap.”
John is pointed out by Jesus to be Elijah. Mt 11:13
John denies being Elijah Jn 1:19
John is said to be the "spirit of Elijah" Lk 1:17
Elijah came from the land east of the Jordan (wilderness), to wage war, in the name of the God of his fathers, against the worship of Baal. He was faithful to the old customs by his simple dress, wearing an assortment of animal skins and a leather belt (2Kings 8).
John is a Levite from which the priesthood of Aaron descends.
According to scripture, he is not mentioned as going through the ceremonial rituals of purification to be an priest. This could be because the priesthood was never officially sanctioned after the destruction of the first temple. God is preparing an entirely different covenant. John is purifying the people that have returned into the land for the new covenant that is being implemented by God.
1st point of exegesis is the study of the life and travels of Jesus that foreshadow future events.

Jesus was from Nazareth (southwest Galilee region). The sea of Galilee is a giant spring full of life which represents heaven
Jesus descends from Galilee to the Jordan where there is a baptism symbolizing life and death and Jesus' coming down to earth as a man. (crucifixion)
Jesus descends even further to the Dead Sea wilderness (Sheol) to take on Azazel and to overcome Israel's sins. Azazel is the mountain where the scapegoat would be pushed off the cliff with the sins of Israel right at the dead sea.
Jesus ascends to Jerusalem (resurrection)
Jesus ascends back to Galilee (ascension)
Jesus does not return to Nazareth to live because they don't believe Him.
Instead He goes up to the most northern part of Galilee Capernaum. (a higher position / glorified)
At an appointed time He descends back down to Jerusalem (2nd coming) entering Jerusalem on a donkey, later to be a horse. People come out of the city to meet him (rapture) as he is coming to the city
Before Jesus goes to Jerusalem, He stops in Bethany, where women are called out of the house and Lazarus is raised (life from the dead for the Jews). - Rm 11:15

John is involved in the story symbolically with the death of Messiah (baptism) in the wilderness. The wilderness is symbolized in the old testament as where sin and death reign (the east).
Adam and Eve were removed from the garden and sent into the wilderness (east of Eden). Jesus had to be baptized (die) before going into the wilderness (Sheol) and freeing the captives (Israel) from their sins.
Many view John as the forerunner to the coming Messiah, but there were many forerunners, and John being in the spirit of Elijah was the final forerunner.
He is the one from the priesthood, that was a prophet, that would purify the people and relinquish everything he was and did to the one of which he prophesied.
John is the water before the wine.
He is the most righteous one that has ever lived (Mt 11:11) giving way to the perfect one that was able to take Israel's sins upon Himself.
John is the trumpet shouting in the wilderness that the first dreadful day of the Lord is at hand, in which the Lamb was to receive the full wrath of God for all sin.
Shouting (trumpets) preparing the coming of the Lord
Day of the Lord #1
Mt 3:2 - Repent, for the kingdom of heaven is at hand.
For this is he that was spoken of by the prophet Elijah, saying, The voice of one crying in the wilderness, Prepare ye the way of the Lord, make his paths straight.
Day of the Lord #2
1Thess 4:16 -  For the Lord Himself will descend from heaven with a shout, with the voice of an archangel, and with the trumpet of God.
Trinitarian views
There are many O.T. passages where the aspects of the trinity were working separately (geographically) but in unison for the will of God.
At the baptism of Jesus all aspects of God funnel in, coming to a focal point on the person of Messiah. The focal point of all 3 aspects of God, Logos, Spirit, Power are the accumulation of what will be the driving force of the New Covenant, being the occupation of a new kind of temple, Jesus being the first of it's kind.
The first temple - occupied by Jehovah, then forsaken due to idolatry, and destroyed
The 2nd temple - Never occupied, but visited by the Son, then forsaken due to idolatry of tradition over the New Covenant, and destroyed
The 3rd temple - a temple of flesh, occupied by the Spirit of God in which God proclaims, "I will never leave you nor forsake you"
John in the spirit of Elijah is the one to pour the water on the burnt offering that is Jesus before fire (God's wrath) comes down to consume the offering. He is the priest that washes the entrails and legs (Lev 1:9) -  "but he shall wash its entrails and its legs with water."
Then Jesus provides the blood, receives the wrath of fire and ascends  - an offering made by fire, a sweet aroma to the Lord. (An aroma ascends and this sacrifice and ascension is accepted by God)
The life of John in the gospels is short, but so much is foreshadowed in his role as the purifier that prepares Israel for the ultimate sacrifice and atonement.

Interesting foreshadows and fulfillments found.  I enjoy types and shadows.  Thanks for the insights.

Your interpretations are interesting, but which denominations subscribe to these views?

@Lesley Messianic Judaism
